# Probability mass function (Grimmett 3.2.2)

Tags: probability

The problem (2a) is stated:
[image]
[image]

Why is $P(X>x) = 2^{-x}$ and not the sum $\sum_{i=x}^{\infty} 2^{-x} = 2^{-x+1}?$ I'd like to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something fundamentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Pr[X = x] = 2^{-x}$ for $x = 1, 2, \ldots$, then $$\Pr[X > x] = \sum_{i = x+1}^\infty 2^{-i} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-(j+x+1)} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-(x+1)} 2^{-j} = 2^{-(x+1)} \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j} = \frac{2^{-(x+1)}}{1-(1/2)} = 2^{-x},$$ as claimed.  What you have calculated instead is $\Pr[X \ge x]$ which is not the same, because your lower index of summation begins at $x$, rather than $x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle P(X>x) = \sum_{n \gt x} P(X=n) =\sum_{n \gt x} 2^{-n} =\sum_{n =x+1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 2^{-x}$$